# Compiling oggvideotools 0.9 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to compile [oggvideotools 0.9](http://www.streamnik.de/oggvideotools.html) on Ubuntu 12.04 server (0.8 is in the ubuntu repos, but I want the current 0.9 trunk version)

```
svn co https://oggvideotools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/oggvideotools oggvideotools
cd oggvideotools/trunk
./autogen.sh
```

and here is what I get :

```
System has changed to run under cmake 

-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for include files HAVE_BZERO_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_BZERO_H - not found.
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDINT_H
-- Looking for include files HAVE_STDINT_H - found
-- checking for module 'theoradec>=1.1'
--   found theoradec, version 1.1.1
-- checking for module 'theoraenc>=1.1'
--   found theoraenc, version 1.1.1
-- checking for module 'vorbis>=1.2.3'
--   found vorbis, version 1.3.2
-- checking for module 'vorbisenc>=1.2.3'
--   found vorbisenc, version 1.3.2
-- checking for module 'ogg>=1.1.0'
--   found ogg, version 1.2.2
-- Theora encoder library found
-- Theora decoder library found
-- Vorbis library found
-- Vorbis encoder library found
-- ogg library found
-- GD library and header found
Creating config.h
Libraries are: theoraenc;theoradec;ogg;theoradec;ogg;vorbis;m;ogg;vorbisenc;vorbis;m;ogg;ogg;GD_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GD_INCLUDE
   used as include directory in directory /var/www/doc.topcleanpackaging.com/extensions/oggvideotools/trunk
   used as include directory in directory /var/www/doc.topcleanpackaging.com/extensions/oggvideotools/trunk/src
   used as include directory in directory /var/www/doc.topcleanpackaging.com/extensions/oggvideotools/trunk/docs
   used as include directory in directory /var/www/doc.topcleanpackaging.com/extensions/oggvideotools/trunk/scripts
GD_LIBRARY
    linked by target "oggvideotools" in directory /var/www/doc.topcleanpackaging.com/extensions/oggvideotools/trunk/src
```

It seems I've well installed all dependencies..but stil not compiling.

Do you have the same issues ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've maneged to build it, this is how I did it after the checkout.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep oggvideotools
./autogen.sh
```

I wish that I had learned the command build-dep earlier it would have saved me a lot of trouble compiling programs. It downloads all dependencies you need to build a package.

Comment: AWSOME ! Thank you a lot, I'm gonna love build-dep...that's something :)

Comment: @Sulliwane Yeah, this works for all Ubuntu packages. However, keep in mind that it will pull in build dependencies for the version of the package is provided for. If these have changed in the version you compile, you'll have to figure it out for yourself. Additionally, the package maintainers could have made build-time choices for you for the package, but you might want it to compile it differently (e.g. not OpenSSL, but GnuTLS - just a random example).